# Remove duplicates, but keeping only the last occurrence in linux file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

**INPUT FILE :**

```
5,,OR1,1000,Nawras,OR,20160105T05:30:17+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,,user,,aaa8016058f008ddceae6329f0c5d551,50293277591,,,30001,C
5,,OR1,1000,Nawras,OR,20160105T05:30:17+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,20160217T01:45:18+0400,,user,aaa8016058f008ddceae6329f0c5d551,50293277591,,,30001,H
5,,OR2,2000,Nawras,OR,20160216T06:30:18+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,,user,,f660818af5625b3be61fe12489689601,50328589469,,,30002,C
5,,OR2,2000,Nawras,OR,20160216T06:30:18+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,20160216T06:30:18+0400,,user,f660818af5625b3be61fe12489689601,50328589469,,,30002,H
5,,OR1,1000,Nawras,OR,20150328T03:00:13+0400,20171230T23:59:59+0400,,user,,22bf18b024e1d4f42ac79943062cf576,50212935879,,,10001,C
5,,OR1,1000,Nawras,OR,20150328T03:00:13+0400,20171230T23:59:59+0400,20150328T03:00:13+0400,,user,22bf18b024e1d4f42ac79943062cf576,50212935879,,,10001,H
0,,OR5,5000,Nawras,OR,20160421T02:45:16+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,,user,,c7c501ac92d85a04bb26c575929e9317,50329769192,,,11001,C
0,,OR5,5000,Nawras,OR,20160421T02:45:16+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,20160421T02:45:16+0400,,user,c7c501ac92d85a04bb26c575929e9317,50329769192,,,11001,H
0,,OR1,1000,Nawras,OR,20160330T02:00:14+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,,user,,d4ea749306717ec5201d264fc8044201,50285524333,,,11001,C
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT :**

```
5,,OR1,1000,UY,OR,20160105T05:30:17+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,20160217T01:45:18+0400,,user,aaa8016058f008ddceae6329f0c5d551,50293277591,,,30001,H 
5,,OR2,2000,UY,OR,20160216T06:30:18+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,20160216T06:30:18+0400,,user,f660818af5625b3be61fe12489689601,50328589469,,,30002,H    
5,,OR1,1000,UY,OR,20150328T03:00:13+0400,20171230T23:59:59+0400,20150328T03:00:13+0400,,user,22bf18b024e1d4f42ac79943062cf576,50212935879,,,10001,H    
0,,OR5,5000,UY,OR,20160421T02:45:16+0400,20191231T23:59:59+0400,20160421T02:45:16+0400,,user,c7c501ac92d85a04bb26c575929e9317,50329769192,,,11001,H
0,,OR1,1000,UY,OR,20160330T02:00:14+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,,user,,d4ea749306717ec5201d264fc8044201,50285524333,,,11001,C*
```

CODE USED :

```
for i in `cat file | awk -F, '{print $13}' | sort | uniq`
do
grep $i file | tail -1 >> TESTINGGGGGGG_SV
done
```

This took much time as the file has 300 million records and which has 65 million uniq records at 13th column .

So i would require a output which can traverse 13th column value - last occurrence in file as the output .

Comment: `perl -F, -le '$seen{$F[12]} = $_;  END { print $seen{$_} for sort keys %seen }'`

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, 'p!=$13 && p0 {print p0} {p=$13; p0=$0} END{print p0}' file
```

expects sorted input.

Please post the timing if you can successfully run the script.

If sorting is not possible, another option is

```
tac file | awk -F, '!a[$13]++' | tac
```

reverse the file, take the first entry for $13 and reverse the results back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work:

```
awk -F, '{rows[$13]=$0} END {for (i in rows) print rows[i]}' file
```

Explanation:

- `rows` is an associative array indexed by field 13 `$13`, the element of the array indexed by `$13` gets overwritten every time there's a duplicate of field 13; its value is the whole line `$0`.

But this is inefficient in terms of memory because of the space needed to save the array.

An improvement to the above solution that's still not using sorting is to just save the line numbers in the associative array:

```
awk -F, '{rows[$13]=NR}END {for(i in rows) print rows[i]}' file|while read lN; do sed "${lN}q;d" file; done
```

Explanation:

- `rows` as before but the values are the line numbers and not the whole lines
- `awk -F, '{rows[$13]=NR}END {for(i in rows) print rows[i]}'` file outputs a list of row numbers containing the sought lines
- `sed "${lN}q;d"` fetches line number `lN` from `file`

Comment: Have you though about how much memory your program will use? 65 million unique records. If each record is 50 bytes it will become around 3 GB of raw data, without counting what AWK needs to keep the array structured. Calculate it yourself `perl -le 'print 65_000_000 * 50 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024'`